# setting startlevel for OSGI bundle

Tags: osgi, glassfish-3, apache-felix

(I use glassfish 3.1, felix)

I have a log bundle that needs to be started before other bundles in my glassfish server.

Is there a way to configure startlevel for a single OSGI bundle? Any of the following ways will be fine: configuring a properties file, solution on java side, header in bundle manifest.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Felix, you can change the launcher properties (for instance, `conf/config.properties`) to start bundles with different start levels. You can use the [`felix.auto.deploy.install.<n>`](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html#ApacheFelixFrameworkConfigurationProperties-launcher) properties for that.

To set the framework's initial startlevel, you can use the configuration property `org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning`, see section 4.2.2 of the core spec for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The default value of "org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning" is 1? So the n in "felix.auto.deploy.install.<n>" must >= 1?

Comment: The default startlevel is indeed 1. So, you set your logging bundle to be on `felix.auto.deploy.install.1` (or `..start.1`, for that matter), and the rest of the bundles on some higher level.

Comment: I configured the startLevel inside cfg files, as described here: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-file-install.html