# Glassfish crashes when I restart the server with osgi bundle

Tags: java, glassfish, osgi, glassfish-3

I have a osgi bundle which I successfully deployed on Glassfish 3.1.2. This is the bundle activator:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.util.Properties;
import org.DX_57.osgi.SH_27.api.SessionHandle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
import org.osgi.framework.Filter;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;
import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker;

public class SessionHandleActivator implements BundleActivator {

    // Define Datasource name
    public static final String DSNAME = "jdbc/Oracle";
    public ServiceTracker st;

    // Register the Java method as OSGI Service when the bundle is deployed
    @Override
    public void start(final BundleContext bc) throws Exception {
        debug("Session Handle 27 Activator started");

        /*
         * Register the Datasource as Service in order to be used into the
         * bundle later from the Java methods
         */
        Filter filter = bc.createFilter("(&" + "(" + Constants.OBJECTCLASS
                + "=" + DataSource.class.getName() + ")" + "(jndi-name="
                + DSNAME + ")" + ")");
        st = new ServiceTracker(bc, filter, null) {

            @Override
            public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference) {

                DataSource ds = (DataSource) bc.getService(reference);
                try {
                    debug(ds.getConnection().toString());
                    // For session handle 
                    SessionHandle sh = new SessionHandleImpl();
                    sh.setDataSource(ds);
                    /*
                     * Register the Java methods insight the bundle in order to
                     * be used
                     */
                    ServiceRegistration registerService = bc.registerService(SessionHandle.class.getName(), sh, new Properties());

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }

                return super.addingService(reference);
            }

            @Override
            public void removedService(ServiceReference reference,
                    Object service) {
                super.removedService(reference, service);
            }
        };
        st.open();
    }

    // Remove the OSGI service when the bundle is undeployed
    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext bc) throws Exception {
        boolean ungetService = bc.ungetService(bc.getServiceReference(SessionHandle.class.getName()));
        st.close();
        debug("Session Handle 27 Activator stopped");
    }

    // Show debug information when the OSGI bundle is deployed
    private void debug(String msg) {
        System.out.println("BundleActivator: " + msg);
    }
}
```

When I restart the Glassfish server the server crashes and I get this error stack:

```
[#|2012-07-08T12:38:16.568+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase|_ThreadID=67;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Expanded at file:/tmp/osgiapp5717459413008665895/|#]

[#|2012-07-08T12:38:17.205+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:674)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:324)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2018)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:672)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:617)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1096)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:922)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:867)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:658)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.parseURL(URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.java:372)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:612)
    ... 27 more
|#]

[#|2012-07-08T12:38:17.233+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC1306: Startup of context  failed due to previous errors|#]

[#|2012-07-08T12:38:17.244+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: PWC2769: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5571)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5384)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2018)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
|#]

[#|2012-07-08T12:38:17.245+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2018)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:674)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:324)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:672)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:617)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1096)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:922)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:867)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:658)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.parseURL(URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.java:372)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:612)
    ... 27 more
|#]

[#|2012-07-08T12:38:17.250+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|No default web.xml|#]

[#|2012-07-08T12:38:17.253+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2018)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
|#]

[#|2012-07-08T12:38:17.254+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: jndi
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
|#]

[#|2012-07-08T12:38:17.254+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app|#]

[#|2012-07-08T12:38:17.258+0300|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgihttp|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|standardContext = StandardEngine[glassfish-web].StandardHost[__asadmin].StandardContext[/osgi]|#]

[#|2012-07-08T12:38:17.301+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app|#]
```

Can you help me to fix the problem?

Comment: Pl. report it at users(at)glassfish.java.net

Comment: I have done this: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18893 and     http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/error-when-trying-restart-glassfish-osgi-bundles-server-crashes

Answer (score 1):

I think your bundle is started too early when you restart. Something registers the jndi url protocol, which went fine the first time because that had already happened when you deployed it, but the *second* time, the OSGi environment is revitalized, and restarted much earlier, before JNDI was registered as a valid protocol.

I'm no Glassfish guru, I'm unsure what is the best way to proceed here, maybe you can prevent the whole revitalizing process by specifying org.osgi.framework.storage.clean, maybe you can increase the start level of your bundle (so it will start later) and prevent this problem, maybe you can somehow detect when the jndi protocol gets registered and wait for that?

Comment: This might help, setting the start level seems to me the most straightforward way of dealing with this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611387/setting-startlevel-for-osgi-bundle